# Zookeeper version for solr 4.10.3

Tags: solr, solr4, apache-zookeeper

Im using `solr 4.10.3` with external `zookeeper` ensemble, So I need to know that which `zookeeper` version will be suitable for this version of solr?
 I tried with `ZK 3.4.6` and worked fine.
Is there any recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Setting+Up+an+External+ZooKeeper+Ensemble),  the best practice is to keep your version of ZooKeeper updated with the latest version distributed with Solr.